# What is the origin of "ex"?

Tags: etymology

> Ex-wife, ex-boyfriend.

Does ***ex*** have a full form?

Google dictionary has this information about the origin of *ex:*

[image]

But what is the origin of the usage as a prefix in the words like *ex-wife, ex-boyfriend*?

Comment: this a duplicate of a duplicate. Use the search, young padawan.

Comment: @vectory, not able to locate the original. Mind giving the link please?

Answer (score 19):

The prefix *[ex-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ex-)* is of Latin origin but the words *ex-wife, ex-boyfriend* are an extended use of Latin phrases such as *ex consule, ex magistro equitum*,  (one who) from being consul, master of knights (where *ex-* is prefixed to titles of office or dignity). Later such phrases were being replaced by *exconsul, exmagister*. They are formed in the same manner as the compounds *proconsul, propraetor* which had been developed from the older *pro consule, pro praetore*.

*OED* explains further how the adapted forms passed into other languages and when it have become common in English:

> In medieval Latin this usage was greatly extended, such forms as *ex-Augustus* (‘ex-emperor’) being of frequent occurrence. Some words of this formation (e.g. *ex-professor*) passed in adapted forms into Italian and French, and on the analogy of these *ex-* was prefixed to Romanic words. The English use, imitated from French, seems to have first become common towards the end of the 18th cent.

*OED*'s earliest citation is from 1398:

> Ex~consul is he that leuyth the offyce of Consul.
>
> <sub>J. Trevisa tr. Bartholomew de Glanville *De Proprietatibus Rerum* (1495) xiv. xlviii. 484</sub>

Note: *De Proprietatibus Rerum (On the Order of Things)* is an encyclopedia dating from the 13th century.   Although it is often described as a bestiary, its focus encompasses theology and astrology as well as the natural sciences (as understood in 1240). [*Source: http://spcoll.library.uvic.ca/*]

Comment: I can't see how *ex consule*, meaning *(one who) from being consul*, is to be interpreted as ***former** consul*. Am I misreading or is there a sentence that, if inserted, would make it more obvious to slower souls like myself? I'm sensing that the key lies in *leuyth* which I'm guessing to be a conjugation of *lay*... Or am I totally off?

Comment: @KonradViltersten  I think *leuyth* comes from *leve*, leave.  "Ex-consul is he that leaveth the office of Consul."

Comment: @augurar Oh, that makes perfect sense. At least for what the 98's definition considers. However, it still doesn't explain how *ex* mean *former* - be that former consul, former wife or whatever. Care to shed some extra light to assist my grey cells in the process, please?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't understand the problem…if one "comes from" being a consul, that means one has left being a consul. Used to be a consul and isn't anymore.

Comment: @JohnPeyton Oh, I realized it the way you mean. For me, *coming from something* is *being it*. Might be influenced by "*he comes from money*" meaning "*he **is** rich*". But I see how you meant. Got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Glad it makes sense now!

Comment: I don't agree that "comes from" transparently implied having left, if *I come from the ministry to tell you ...* is the more usual usage. This would be a question for Latin.SE, anyway. Maybe it helps to consider *de-*: *ex ante*, but *de novo*, and later Italian *della*, French *de* as prepositions "of, from", in contrast to *ex* "out, outta", *Deus ex machina* (cp. Ger. *ausgemacht[-er Schwachsinn]*, literally *outmade nonsense*, or rather *made up*?). Yet, I can't help but think that *expell*, and the like contributed to *to ex someone*, if not *to strike,* ***cross out*** (of a list).

Comment: ... which gives "straight outta Compton" an interesting spin, *escape from the ghetto*, haha

Answer (score 12):

[**ex-**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ex-) is defined as:

> a prefix meaning “out of,” “from,” and hence “utterly,” “thoroughly,” and sometimes meaning “not” or “without” or indicating a former title, status, etc.

**Origin of ex-**

**ex-** is a word-forming element, which in English simply means "former" in this case, or  mainly "out of, from," but also "upwards, completely, deprive of, without. It most likely originated in Latin, where *ex* meant "out of, from within," and perhaps, in some cases also from Greek cognate *ex*, *ek.*

Comment: In latin, one the multiple meanings of the word "ex" (written "e" before a conson) is "out of", e.g "ex urbe exire" [to go out of the city] or "e vita exire" [to die]. *Ex* has a different sense in "ex-libris" where it means *from within*.

Comment: `It most likely originated in Latin`. Why only *most likely*? it is the same word, has the same meaning, it exists identically in Latin languages, and a lot of words originate from Latin. Plus the source you cite indicates its origin is Latin.

Comment: @Graffito *Ex* has at least a dozen different meanings in Latin, but none of them is "from within."  The *ex* in *ex libris* means "from" in the sense of origin.  So "*ex libris* John" means "from the library of John"; it's a common expression founds on bookplates.

Comment: Exodontist (medical expert who is a specialist of taking teeth **out of** gums), extract (taking **out of** something), excreta (waste matter coming **out of** our body) are etymologically based on this meaning of `ex-` that you have mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 3):

Defining "ex," with or without the hyphen, solely as a reference to "past" or "former," ignores its use in an entirely different direction and intent. "Ex" is used (without a hyphen) in commonly used Latin phrases, and ***almost never*** suggests "former" or "past." In such uses, "ex" denotes present tense. For example:

- ex Deo — *from God*
- ex parte — *by one party* or *for one party*
- ex tempore — *this instant*, *right away*, or *immediately*

Another Latin phrase is "ex officio," which one frequently finds written with the hyphen inserted erroneously. This Latin phrase means *from the office*, in reference to someone who *presently* has a right or privilege because of an office currently held. It is regularly used correctly today in business, academics, and law for serious purposes.

Written as "ex-officio," though, it conveys, roughly, the opposite (only roughly because it is not proper Latin). It is used in this way where it should not, such as in news stories, magazines, and books. Some dictionaries actually define it as "former official," with no reference to its real meaning. Allowing this isn't word creep or poisoning a dry well. It is tantamount to poisoning a well filled with fresh water.